# Javascripts "setInterval()" used with jQuery animations results in a function queue up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

### What's happening

Okay, so I've made a function on my front page where some products are shown besides each other, fading out, changing products and fading back in every 5 seconds. The code looks like this:

```
var t;

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Some pre-animation stuff, like loading the products etc.

    // Initialize animation timer
    t = setInterval("changeProducts();", 5000);
};

function changeProducts() {
    // Fade out
    $("#anfBox").fadeTo(200, 0.01, function() {

    // Change products

    // Fade back in
    $("#anfBox").fadeTo(200, 1);
    });
}
```

It all looks fine and runs as it should, except when i go to another window for a minute and then comes back, the `changeProducts` function is executed rapidly a few times (depending on how long i've been away). The products fade out, change fades in again, and then repeats instantly, where there should be a ~5 second delay.

### What I've tried

So what I **think** I need to do is use something like `clearInterval(t)` when the focus is lost from the window, then re-initialize the timer when the window is re-entered, i just don't know how to do that, and i'm having a hard time finding anything useful on google.

I'm thinking maybe there's allso a way to run the animations even if the window is not in focus to avoid the function-queue.

I've also tried using `setTimeout()` instead but with no luck.

Any ideas on how to avoid the animation-queue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the latest browser updates lots of browsers now stop execution of code when current page or tab is not active. When you return that tab/window it executes all of queued actions and you see a rush of effect running each after.

Simply check effect queue before apply another effect, if queue's length is 0 then apply.

Try this ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/MnrVv/));

```
var t;

function changeProducts() {
    // Fade out
    var $anfBox = $("#anfBox"),
        queue = $anfBox.queue('fx');
    if (queue && queue.length === 0) {
        $anfBox.fadeTo(200, 0.01, function() {
            // Change products
            // Fade back in
            $anfBox.fadeTo(200, 1);
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Some pre-animation stuff, like loading the products etc.
    // Initialize animation timer
    t = setInterval(changeProducts, 5000);
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks allot. :)
The jsfiddle link is a nice touch to the answer as well.